# How to generate a rotated (by 90 degrees) logistic sigmoid function in Python

Tags: python

I created this Python function to generate a sigmoid function where I can modify position and width:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def sigmoid(x,a,b):
# sigmoid function with parameters a = center; b = width
return 1/(1+np.exp(-(x-a)/b))
```

For example changing the parameter b I can make it wider or narrower:

```
# testing changing sigmoid width (and slope at the same time) - parameter b
 x = np.linspace(0,10,256)
 y = sigmoid(x,5,1) # default
 ymax = sigmoid(x,5,1.75)
 ymin = sigmoid(x,5,0.25)
 # Create the plot
 plt.plot(x,y,lw=2,color='black')
 plt.plot(x,ymax,lw=2,color='green')
 plt.plot(x,ymin,lw=2,color='orange')
```

The above is fairly straightforward.

But what if I wanted a rotated sigmoid function?  I simulated my intended result "graphically" in the figure below:

[image]

which I plotted by just creating a new independent variable x ('test' variable below) and swapping x and y:

```
test=np.linspace(0,1,128)
plt.plot(y2*255,test,lw=2,color='yellow')
```

Is there a way to achieve this shape with a new sigmoid-like function, or to rotate the original?

It has occurred to me that I could use something like `-np.sinh(x)` but what I'd really like is to have a similar exponential expression with parameters a and b to control the curve's shape.

This question is also posted on Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851287/how-to-generate-a-rotated-by-90-degrees-logistic-sigmoid-function-in-python

Comment: What about applying a transformation (rotation in this case) to your $x-y$ data?

Comment: Hi nicoguaro, that's one of the things I was thinking about but I don't have any prior experience with it. HOw would you do it?

Comment: You can rotate a vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ by an angle $\theta$ using a rotation matrix, like
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ 
y'
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}$$
Just as described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: OK, I've use that before in other subject matters. I will give it a try, have to figure out how to do it in Python. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `numpy`, like  
    
    import numpy as np  
    R = np.array([[np.cos(t),-np.sin(t)],[np.sin(t),np.cos(t)]])  
    X_new = np.dot(R,X_old)  

where `X_old` is a $2\times n$ array, $n$ the number of data you have.

Comment: Looking good. Why don't you make this comment an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want the [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function?

Answer (score 3):

I am turning my comments into an answer as a petition of Mycarta. One easy option that I would use is to rotate the $(x,y)$. To rotate a vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ by an angle $\theta$ you can use a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ 
y'
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}$$

In Python this can be easily done as

```
import numpy as np
R = np.array([[np.cos(t),-np.sin(t)],[np.sin(t),np.cos(t)]])
X_new = np.dot(R,X_old)
```

where `X_old` is a $2\times n$ array, being $n$ the number of data you have.

Comment: Hi nicoguaro, I choose k20's answer as it is the best out of two valid solutions to my problem. As soon as my reputation reaches 15 I will come back and upvote your answer. And thanks for the explanations.